# JavaScript to gather visitor information/stats

Tags: javascript, browser, web

I am looking for a piece of code, or even a list of all browsers' properties JavaScript can access so I can prepare my own stats system.
I'm not looking for anything that server-side parser can get (e.g. Agent, referrer, etc.).

---

I am not interested in external solutions like Google Analytics.
The reason for this is that I want to run it within company's Intranet and I require it to be internal solution.

Comment: I believe I've found a solution: [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) It looks very, very promising...

Answer (score 8):

#### Updated Answer...

You can run Google Analytics on your intranet too: http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55510

#### Original Answer...

Have you considered using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics)?

It's got an impressive [list of features](http://www.google.com/analytics/features.html), and even a [Narrated Tour](http://www.google.com/analytics/tour.html).

"Installation" is simple. Just copy/paste a small block of javascript into your website template.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sizlopedia.com](http://www.sizlopedia.com/wp-content/uploads/google-analytics-revamped.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Agreed, Google Analytics is great, simple to install and very easy to use!

Comment: on normal web projects I do use Analytics and true, it is rather useful.

What I need is to do a survey on company's Intranet and I don't want to use any external solutions.

Comment: You can run GA from an intranet: http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55510

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Still, don't want to involve Analytics or any other stats provider, since considerable amount of PCs that are going to be surveyed do not have Internet access.

Comment: You may be interested in the Navigator Object then: http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javanavigator.html

Comment: You're going to be taking on a massive work-load if you go the Navigator-Object route.

Comment: I've added a new answer with another suggestion too.

Answer (score 3):

For Intranets, you might find some benefit in [AwStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), or a similar application.

- [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)
- [Unica NetTracker](http://www.sclanalytics.com/products/nettracker) ([Online Demo](http://www.sclanalytics.com/products/nettracker/webinar))
- [Affinium NetInSight](http://www.sclanalytics.com/products/netinsight) ([Flash Demo](http://www.sclanalytics.com/products/netinsight/flash) | [Online Demo](http://www.sclanalytics.com/products/netinsight/webinar))
- [AwStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)
- [Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/)